# Spaces in FFMPEG Input Thwart Execution

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pathlib

What's so baffling, is why spaces in the audio input seem to work fine, but spaces in the video input break things.
This fetches random images from a directory, pairs them with random audio clips and joins them into an mp4 video.

```
def makeAudioImgMovs():
    randImgs = getImgs()
    compAudClips = makeAudioClips()
    audioJpgs = dict(zip(randImgs,compAudClips)) #Heres where we join the completed audio clips and the jpgs into a dict
    for jpg, aud in audioJpgs.items():
        print(f'The img is {jpg}, the type of the img is {type(jpg)} the aud is {aud} the type of the aud is {type(aud)}')
        subprocess.call('ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -loop 1 -i "{0}" -i "{1}"\
        -filter:v \
        "fade=in:st=0:d=1, fade=out:st=10:d=1,scale=720:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" \
         -filter:a "afade=in:st=0:d=1, afade=out:st=10:d=1" \
        -c:v libx264 -t 11 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset faster -shortest -c:a aac {2}.mp4'.format(jpg,aud,timePath/(pathlib.Path(jpg).stem)),shell=True)
makeAudioImgMovs()
```

The print statement is writing what is in the dict of audioJpgs list. For example...

The img is 2021-09-02-1-40/ponty_me.jpg, the type of the img is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> the aud is 2021-09-02-1-40/Jms Brn like it is like it was.aiff the type of the aud is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>

The img is 2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack 2.tiff, the type of the img is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> the aud is 2021-09-02-1-40/Lola_Fay.mp3 the type of the aud is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>

[NULL @ 0x7fe503021400] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack'
2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack: Invalid argument

The img is 2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack 5.tiff, the type of the img is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> the aud is 2021-09-02-1-40/M Miller Lonnie's Lament.aiff the type of the aud is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>

[NULL @ 0x7fd32a854c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack'
2021-09-02-1-40/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack: Invalid argument

The img is 2021-09-02-1-40/10_021390_danny? 1_jpg.jpg, the type of the img is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> the aud is 2021-09-02-1-40/i_got_to_rock.mp3 the type of the aud is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>

[NULL @ 0x7f8449835800] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2021-09-02-1-40/10_021390_danny?'
2021-09-02-1-40/10_021390_danny?: Invalid argument

The img is 2021-09-02-1-40/11_021390_danny_2_jpg.jpg, the type of the img is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'> the aud is 2021-09-02-1-40/M Miller Power.aiff the type of the aud is <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>

The last pair of img/aud complete fine and write an mp4. Notice there, that the audio file has spaces in it!
Notice that the errors 'Invalid argument' get thrown where there is a space in the jpg file name.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try making a string of your command, e.g. `cmd = f'ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel ...'` and then printing that string for examination before passing it to  `subprocess.call(cmd, ...)`

Comment: Very confusing... printing out the ffmpeg command gives me what looks like a well-formatted input.
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -loop 1 -i "2021-09-02-12-20/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack 3.tiff" ...`
But copying it directly into the command line gives me the same error.
`Unable to find a suitable output format for '2021-09-02-12-20/1966taxiToMassFromMomBack'` 
Where ffmpeg has cut off the path at the space in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes here:

```
ffmpeg ... -c:a aac "{2}.mp4"
```

Comment: OMG sir you are a hero!